# How to pass a success response from the ajax request to the html template?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a page with the list of photos.

albums/show.html.erb:

```
<% @images.each do |image| %>
  <article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4" data-image-id="<%= image.id %>">
    <%= image_tag(image.image.url(:thumb), class: "thumb") %>
    <p class="description"><%= truncate(image.description, length: 100, omission: '...') %></p>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

album controller:

```
def show
  @user = @album.user
  @image = Image.new
  @album_id = params[:id]
  @images = Image.where(album_id: @album_id, user_id: @user.id).order(created_at: :DESC)
end
```

after click on a photo, i make ajax-request and display modal window with the photo image.

js:

```
// detail image
$('#thumbsList .thumb').on('click', function(){
  var imageId = $(this).closest('article').attr('data-image-id');

  $.ajax({
    url: '/images/' + imageId,
    type: 'GET',
    data: { image_id: imageId },
    success: function(image){
      console.log(image.id); // OK
      console.log(image.description); //OK
      $('#modalDetailImage').modal();
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      handleModal('Невозможно редактировать альбом', 'Ошибка на сервере. Повторите попытку через некоторое время. ', 'f00', 2000);
    }        
  })
});
```

images controller:

```
def show
  if @image_detail = Image.find(params[:image_id])
    render json: @image_detail, :status => 200 
  else
    render nothing: true, :status => 404 
  end
end
```

application.html.erb:

```
......
...........
....
....
<div class="modal fade modal_detail_image" id="modalDetailImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAboutLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ---------------<%= OUTPUT DETAIL PHOTO IMAGE %>--------------------------     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I do not know how to pass a variable from ajax function `success` to `<%= OUTPUT DETAIL PHOTO IMAGE %>`

i use paperclip gem. this gem has very longer paths for every image

Comment: Maybe you want pass an image path to modal? Or just message from ajax response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, just append the success message to a div. From how it looks, your variable is just text:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divID');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'YOUR MESSAGE';
```

Comment: to show the images need to perform expression: image_tag(@user.avatar.url(:thumb)  . in JS-file this expressions are not met

Comment: Is the output of @user.avatar.url(:thumb) an url?

Comment: alexsmn, yes. is output a longer url. this url generate gem 'paperclip'. it look like that: /home/kalinin/rails/phs/public/system/images/images/000/003/357/medium/123.jpg

Comment: and what if instead of passing the url to image_tag helper, you pass it to <img alt="" src="URL" />  which is the same thing with the helper that you want to use, and if I understood what you want all you need to do is to pass that url on success, to a img block using js.